# How can I move an uploaded file from slave server to master server using php ssh connection?

Tags: php, ssh

My application is running in a master slave server. If a file upload request is going to slave server, I need to move that file to master server. Now it is only uploading to slave. It wont lsync with the master.

How can I move the uploaded file from the slave to master during the file upload time using ssh in php?

Server platform is ubuntu with apache and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use rsync over ssh run by cron. First execute:

```
$ crontab -e
```

And add something like:

```
*/5 * * * * rsync -e 'ssh -i [identity_file]' [src_dir] [user]@[host]:[trg_dir]
```

This command will sync your directories every 5 minutes. Feel free to adjust '*/5 * * * *' pattern to your needs.

Finally:

```
$ man crontab
```

And:

```
$ man rsync
```